# How to handle data from xlsx file in Python

Tags: python

These are the named ranges in an uploaded xlsx sheet, the titles are annoying and I wanted to classify them for easier calling in throughout the code.

Fairly new, and unsure how I would be able to make the below look cleaner and be more efficient if I was going to add more named ranges

````
VIC_Male = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Victoria ;'
QL_Male = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Queensland ;'
SA_Male = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  South Australia ;'
WA_Male = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Western Australia ;'
TAS_Male = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Tasmania ;'
NT_Male = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Northern Territory ;'
ACT_Male = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Australian Capital Territory ;'
TOTAL_Male = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Australia ;'
NSW_Female = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  New South Wales ;'
VIC_Female = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Victoria ;'
QL_Female = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Queensland ;'
SA_Female = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  South Australia ;'
WA_Female = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Western Australia ;'
TAS_Female = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Tasmania ;'
NT_Female = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Northern Territory ;'
ACT_Female = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Australian Capital Territory ;'
TOTAL_Female = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Australia ;'
NSW_Persons = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  New South Wales ;'
VIC_Persons = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Victoria ;'
QL_Persons = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Queensland ;'
SA_Persons = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  South Australia ;'
WA_Persons = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Western Australia ;'
TAS_Persons = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Tasmania ;'
NT_Persons = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Northern Territory ;'
ACT_Persons = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Australian Capital Territory ;'
TOTAL_Persons = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Australia ;'```
````

Comment: put it in a file and never look at it again.

Comment: There is a huge difference between code (logic) and data. What you asking here has nothing to deal with python...this is just data....You could build a generic and "clean" data structure in order to deal with it inside your logic (python code)....

Comment: What would be the best way to do that then ? @yAzou

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have this csv file (I added titles here in the first line but you can also have the same file without title, in the code bellow i commented the line that you can remove if you do not have titles) :

```
"ResultType;Gender;Country
Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Victoria ;
Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Queensland ;
Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  South Australia ;
Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Western Australia ;
Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Tasmania ;
Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Northern Territory ;
"
```

You can begin by making a data structure that corresponds to your data :

```py
class Record():
    def __init__(self, ResultType, Gender, Country):
        self.ResultType = ResultType
        self.Gender = Gender
        self.Country = Country
```

Then create an empty list

```py
My_records = []
```

Then open the csv file with the csv library and for each line of it create an instance of your data structure (here the `Record` class).

```py
with open('records.txt') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        #You can remove this part if your csv file has no column name lines
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}') #
            line_count += 1
        else:
            instance = Record(row[0], row[1], row[2])
            My_records.append(instance)
```

All in one :

```py
import csv

class Record():
    def __init__(self, ResultType, Gender, Country):
        self.ResultType = ResultType
        self.Gender = Gender
        self.Country = Country
My_records = []
with open('records.txt') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            instance = Record(row[0], row[1], row[2])
            My_records.append(instance)
```

Now the `My_records` list is a list filled with each line of your CSV file as an instance of class Record. Thus you can manipulate it as you wish.

For example :

```py
All_countries = set([record.Country.strip() for record in My_records])
print(All_countries)
```

**OUTPUT** (All unique country present in your data) :

```
{'Northern Territory', 'Tasmania', 'South Australia', 'Queensland', 'Western Australia', 'Australia', 'Australian Capital Territory', 'New South Wales', 'Victoria'}
```

Of course you have many usefull libraries that aims to deal with those kind of stuff, like `pandas` but here I gave you example in plain python (using the csv included library though)

By the way, if your file is an xls file, those libraries (like pandas) has this kind of tools (but you'll have to `pip install pandas` first) :

```py
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_excel("record.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet1")
```

This code will actually replace the lines in the above example :

```py
with open('records.txt') as csv_file:

    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    ...
```

The rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

````
VIC_Male       = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Victoria ;'
QL_Male        = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Queensland ;'
SA_Male        = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  South Australia ;'
WA_Male        = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Western Australia ;'
TAS_Male       = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Tasmania ;'
NT_Male        = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Northern Territory ;'
ACT_Male       = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Australian Capital Territory ;'
TOTAL_Male     = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Male ;  Australia ;'
NSW_Female     = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  New South Wales ;'
VIC_Female     = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Victoria ;'
QL_Female      = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Queensland ;'
SA_Female      = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  South Australia ;'
WA_Female      = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Western Australia ;'
TAS_Female     = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Tasmania ;'
NT_Female      = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Northern Territory ;'
ACT_Female     = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Australian Capital Territory ;'
TOTAL_Female   = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Female ;  Australia ;'
NSW_Persons    = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  New South Wales ;'
VIC_Persons    = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Victoria ;'
QL_Persons     = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Queensland ;'
SA_Persons     = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  South Australia ;'
WA_Persons     = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Western Australia ;'
TAS_Persons    = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Tasmania ;'
NT_Persons     = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Northern Territory ;'
ACT_Persons    = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Australian Capital Territory ;'
TOTAL_Persons  = 'Estimated Resident Population ;  Persons ;  Australia ;'```
````

Comment: I meant making it more compact, like instead of re-naming all the column names so it's not a large block of text.